# C2(U) Unitary Matrix Representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer

[image: Incorrect Unitary Matrix Represenation]

Above is my work for the unitary matrix representation of a C2(U) gate. However, this does not agree with a [link](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~tbrun/Course/lecture12.pdf) I found online for what it  should look like.

Below my work, I have written the equivalent form of the C2(U) gate. How would this unitary matrix representation be written as tensor products prior to simplification?

I have read every wiki page and university notes out there, but am unable to figure out my error.

Please advise.

Comment: Any general advise on the order of ⊗ operation as we write left to right of a quantum circuit would be additionally of help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your mistake is doubling-up the Us instead of doubling-up the controls. You computed the matrix for applying a U to wires 2 and 3 controlled by wire 1, instead of the matrix for applying a U to just wire 3 controlled by wires 1 and 2.

[Quirk](https://github.com/Strilanc/Quantum-Circuit-Inspector) used to show the matrices of operations you hovered over. You can [play around with that old version on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4f5z73v/2/embedded/result/); might help get a feel for how the matrices change as you move the operations around. Note that the endian-ness may be reversed from what you want. Here's what it shows for a doubly-controlled Hadamard applied to four wires:

[image: HCCI matrix]

**Control Value Trick**

A trick you can use for figuring out these matrices is to [define a value for 'control'](http://algorithmicassertions.com/impractical-experiments/2015/05/17/Treating-Controls-like-Values.html). Define the 'control matrix' $C = \begin{bmatrix} c&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. $c$ is the 'control value'. It's not a number, but a special placeholder value that satisfies $c^2 = c\otimes c = c$.

The thing that makes $c$ so special is that we redefine the tensor product so that $c \otimes U = cI$ instead of $cU$. This breaks all kinds of nice invariants that the tensor product usually follows, but we won't need them here.

A doubly-controlled U would equal $C \otimes C \otimes U$. Start computing:

$\begin{bmatrix} c&\\&1\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c&\\&1\end{bmatrix} \otimes U$

$= \begin{bmatrix} c&\\&1\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c\otimes U&0\otimes U\\0\otimes U&1 \otimes U\end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix} c&\\&1\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c I_2 &  \\  & U\end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix} c \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c I_2 &  \\ & U\end{bmatrix}&0 \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c I_2 &  \\  & U\end{bmatrix}\\0 \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c I_2 &  \\  & U\end{bmatrix}&1 \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c I_2 &  \\  & U\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix} cI_4 &  \\  &\begin{bmatrix} c I_2 &  \\  & U\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix} cI_2 &  &  &  \\  & cI_2 &  &  \\  & & c I_2 &  \\  &  &  & U\end{bmatrix}$

Then we clean out the $c$'s to get

$\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} I_2 &  &  &  \\  & I_2 &  &  \\  & & I_2 &  \\  &  &  & U\end{bmatrix}$

Which is the right answer.

Comment: Could you @CraigGidney please give me the representation of the equivalent gate from my picture. Seeing one example written out (prior to simplification) would really help.

Comment: I am confused because we cannot use this trick when the control is between 1 and 3 (such as the lower situation in the photo)

Comment: @NewUser8991 When $U$ isn't the right-most matrix in the tensor product, you have to expand it into like $\begin{bmatrix} u_a&u_b\\u_c&u_d \end{bmatrix}$ in order to continue symbolically evaluating.

Comment: Sorry @CraigGidney, let me clarify. Would I write C⊗U⊗I if the control is 1 on 3, and 2 is not acted on?

Comment: @NewUser8991 No, you'd write C⊗I⊗C and find that nothing happened because no operation was being controlled. If there were 5 qubits with controls on 1 and 3, nothing on 2 and 5, and a U on 4, then you'd write C⊗I⊗C⊗U⊗I.